# UICollectionView disappears when refering it from UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to create a `collectionView` and controller, both setup in a XIB. If only `collectionView` is set up, and controller does not refere it, then it works, `collectionView` appears. But when I link them, then `collectionView` disappears from screen, only other subview will shown.

If red outlet is set, `collectionView` disappears, if not set `collectionView` appears. Any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to set `view` instead of `collectionView` in XIB, see image below, I do not know why, but it fixed issue, if somebody could explain why, I would be appreciative. Setting both outlet will mess up thing too.

[image]